# Correct way to combine `bundle exec` and `ruby -r`?

Tags: ruby, bundler

Let's experiment with a random gem, it doesn't matter which.

```rb
# Gemfile
gem "hashie"
```

Let's install our bundle in a (semi) non-standard place, so that `ruby` can't find it:

```sh
bundle install --path=vendor/bundle
ruby -e 'require "hashie"'
# cannot load such file -- hashie (LoadError)
```

As expected, if we add `bundle exec` to the above, then `ruby -e` *can* find our gem:

```sh
bundle exec ruby -e 'puts require "hashie"'
# true
```

But, even with `bundle exec`, `ruby -r` cannot find our gem!

```sh
bundle exec ruby -r hashie -e 'puts "win"'
# cannot load such file -- hashie (LoadError)
```

The only way I have found to combine `bundle exec` and `ruby -r` is:

```sh
bundle exec ruby -r 'bundler/setup' -r hashie -e 'puts "win"'
# win
```

The [documentation for bundle exec](https://bundler.io/v2.0/man/bundle-exec.1.html) does not mention `ruby -r`, so I ask here, is this the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

```
-r 'bundler/setup'
```

is acceptable. It means to "require all of the gems in my Gemfile".

'hashie' could not load its dependencies that is why "LoadError" occurred.

reference: [bundler_setup](https://bundler.io/v1.12/bundler_setup.html)

Comment: Thanks, that link is helpful. Though, I think `Bundler.setup` only configures `$LOAD_PATH`. It doesn't actually `require` any gems.